# recursive query with perl

Tags: algorithm, perl, dbi, graph-algorithm

I have the following table on db  which has 2 columns :

```
from      to    
00001     00002
00001     00003
00002     00003
00002     00004
00003     00001
00003     00004
00002     00004
00004     00002
00005     00003
00005     00001
00006     00007
00009     00006
```

I need to get with perl and dbi  the  connection of specific number, for example the output of 00001 will be the below connection :

```
00001 00002 0003 00004 00005
```

because 00001 connected to 00002 and 00003 and 00002 and 00003 connected to those new number  00004 and 00005 .

Is there an algorithm to implement this and what is the best solution in perl to implement such algorithm ?

Comment: If you have (1,2),(1,3) what is the output of 1?

Comment: it will be 1,2,3 because 1 is connected to 2 and to 3

Comment: @smith Please fix the example -- there is no connection to 5 from 1,2,3, or 4.

Comment: Which database are you using? Some databases will let you do this with a single query.

Comment: @mu - and others let you write a `while` loop to do that

Comment: @DVK: Which is why every question involving a database should include "I am using database X" or an explicit "I want a database-agnostic solution".

Comment: @muistooshort - you've been on SO long enough to not hope for well formulated questions, no? Abandon hope all ye who enters... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you want to find a connected subtree (it's a directed graph, e.g. a tree, so you want tree algos).

This is done using tree search algorithms - DFS (Depth First Search) or BFS (Breath First Search). You can implement either one in SQL or in Perl (or in a DBI mix though it's more annoying than pure SQL or pure Perl solution).

The general BFS would be:

- Create a queue (Hint: in Perl, queues and stacks are naturally represented by arrays)
- Store the original node in the queue.
- While the queue is not empty, repeat:

  - Pop the first node `N` off the queue.
  - Mark that node as "traversed". The easiest approach is to set a hash element in a `%seen` hash with a key of `N` to a value of 1.
  - Print `N` to the path
  - Find all the nodes from DB connected *from* N.
  - Add those nodes from the last step that have NOT yet been seen to the end of the queue.
- End loop.

Answer (score -2):

One possible approach:

```
sub AllReachable {
    my ( $dbi, $sql, @todo ) = @_;
    my %done;
    while (@todo) {
        my $res = $dbi->selectcol_arrayref( sprintf $sql, join( ",", @todo ) );
        @done{@todo} = ();
        @todo = grep {!exists $done{$_}} @$res;
    }
    return keys %done;
}

my @result = AllReachable($dbi, 'SELECT DISTINCT to FROM table WHERE from IN (%s)', 1);
```

Comment: @reinierpost: What? Do you understand what it does? No, you don't understand it. It makes same amount of queries as length of longest path. In contrary DVK solution (without source code) does query per vertex. Guess which number of queries is less, dunno.

Comment: @Hynek-Pichi-Vychodil - you seem to be confusing SQL calls with SQL queries. They are not the same and don't necessarily bear the same costs. Re: lack of source code - I have a deep aversion to doing work for people who didn't bother doing ANY work - if you bother looking at my answer history, I've been known to provide page-long code with several versions to people who asked a question which shows they genuinely tried and want to learn how to do better.

Comment: @DVK I know difference between calls and queries but what is better strongly depend on many things including DB type, current graph data and deployment. Mine solution can do order of magnitude less queries depending on data and query parsing and planning can be balanced by number of calls and also latency. Imagine deploy where perl part runs on different machine than SQL server. For example in AWS latency can be easy 200us so even when query processing would be 1ms (unrealistic slow) it will be balanced by 5x times less queries than calls.

Comment: I forgot write _... order of magnitude less queries than your approach calls ..._

Comment: @Hynek-Pichi-Vychodil - too bad you don't know enough about tree traversal to understand that with sufficient tuning BFS takes O(M) queries where M is a tree depth. Which is precisely the # of calls that your code has, **because it implements a BFS**. It merely does so via a bunch of SQL calls vs. 1 call, doing the "seen" logic in Perl instead of SQL.

Comment: @Hynek-Pichi-Vychodil In any case, you were right: I didn't read your code carefully enough.

Comment: @DVK: too bad you don't even know it is not tree but graph. So sad you don't even know BFS. Look, you store nodes (vertices) to queue and according algorithm you described is removing one vertex in each iteration. And generally BFS is algorithm to find path to goal but task is to find all vertices reachable from starting vertex and ... Just implement it and try. So sad for person in your age and reputation make so big mistake.